# PHPmailer sending HTML CODE

Tags: php

I am using PHPmailer to send email.

I have also used HTML = True content type

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                    // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = $Host; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;             // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $Username;  
$mail->Password = $Password; 

$mail->From     = $From;
$mail->FromName = $FromName;

    $mail->AddAddress($To , $ToName);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;               // set word wrap
    $mail->Priority = 1; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject  =  $Subject;
$mail->Body     =  $Body;
```

Once the email is sent i see the actual HTML code instead of the contents please check below

[image]

**Not sure what is the issue **

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to fill the body?

Comment: Are you doing `$mail->Body($your_html_html)`?

Comment: @MarcB yes i am using     $mail->Body     =  $Body;

Comment: D'oh! Right... Body is an attribute, not a method. IN any case, here's the 'official' tutorial on how to send an html mail: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#4

Comment: @MarcB Not sure what yo want to say what should i change in my code above ?

Comment: Where does `$Body` come from?

Comment: @Pekka $Body comes from an WYSIWYG editor

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Calling the `isHTML()` method after the instance `Body` property (I mean `$mail->Body`) has been set solved the problem for me:

```
$mail->Subject = $Subject;
$mail->Body    = $Body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);       // <=== call IsHTML() after $mail->Body has been set.
```

Comment: That is correct but you should never call `$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();` after `$mail->IsHTML(true)`. `ClearCustomHeader` gets rid of your email HTML formatting and instead recipient will receive HTML source code.

Comment: personally I use:
$mail->msgHTML($email_body);

Answer (score 11):

There is `msgHTML()` method, which also call `IsHTML()`.

The name `IsHTML` is confusing...

```
/**
 * Create a message from an HTML string.
 * Automatically makes modifications for inline images and backgrounds
 * and creates a plain-text version by converting the HTML.
 * Overwrites any existing values in $this->Body and $this->AltBody
 * @access public
 * @param string $message HTML message string
 * @param string $basedir baseline directory for path
 * @param bool $advanced Whether to use the advanced HTML to text converter
 * @return string $message
 */
public function msgHTML($message, $basedir = '', $advanced = false)
```

Answer (score 3):

or if you have still problems you can use this

```
$mail->Body =  html_entity_decode($Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.2.7 I use this to send plain text:

```
$mail->set('Body', $body);
```

Comment: I believe he wants his email to show up properly formatted as an HTML email, not as plaintext.

Answer (score -1):

do like this-paste your html code inside your separate html file using GET method.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->WordWrap = 70;                                 
    $mail->addAttachment= $_GET['addattachment']; $mail->AltBody   
    =$_GET['AltBody'];  $mail->Subject = $_GET['subject']; $mail->Body = $_GET['body'];
```

Answer (score -2):

just you need to pass true as an argument to IsHTML() function.

Comment: But he's doing that already! Did you not look at his code...?

Answer (score -2):

all you need to do is just add $mail->IsHTML(true); to the code it works fine..

Comment: He did that already!  Did you not look at his code...?