# PHPMailer doesnt send email if isHTML(true)

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I have just started using PHPMailer and I cant get my HTML emails to send and render properly. I can get them to send fine but when I add the isHTML(true) method the email doesnt send at all. Is there anything I need to put inside the HTML email or layout differently.

Here is the html email:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test email</h1>
    <p>Congratulations, {NAME}</p>
    <p>You have won {PRIZE}</p>
    <img src="{DOMAIN}assets/images/generated_barcodes/actual-000000013.png" alt="Barcode">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the sequence of methods I use to send the email:

```
$this->_mail = new PHPMailer();
$this->_mail->From = FROM_EMAIL;
$this->_mail->FromName = FROM_EMAIL_NAME;
$this->_mail->addAddress($email);
$this->_mail->Subject = $subject;
$this->_mail->Body = $body;
$this->_mail->isHTML(true);

$this->_mail->send()
```

Just to clarify this email sends fine if I comment out the isHTML(true) method but it obviously doesn't render the HTML.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Seems like I just had to use the $this->_mail->msgHTML($body, DOMAIN); method to load in my HTML. But now I have a new issue. The email sends but not while in an AJAX request. I need it to send an email when I post some data with AJAX.

Comment: Don't you need to capitalize `Is`?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't send"? Is there any error? Also try setting up `$this->_mail->AltBody` (if I remember correct)

Comment: <strike>Maybe you got to set isHtml before adding Body content</strike> i was wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code   , as TylerH said it might not work because you got small letter i instead of capital I

Comment: @TylerH not according to the example on github, but ill give it a try!

Comment: @DavidJones I only ask because I've only ever seen it as `IsHTML`... could be wrong :-)

Comment: @ex3v nope no error, I have tried wrapping it in a try catch and the $this->_mail->ErrorInfo is NULL

Comment: @TylerH yep your right, weird how the github documentation writes it as isHTML and not IsHTML! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to check if there are any errors in errors.log

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so it can be accepted, then. PHP is weird

Comment: It may have been `IsHTML` in older versions, but it is definitely `isHTML` now, see [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L650). It's also not capitalised anywhere in documentation. Are you using an old version?

Comment: Nope, I just downloaded a fresh version, see my comments on the answer form TylerH

Answer (score 3):

You should capitalize `Is` for `$this->_mail->IsHTML(true);`.

Comment: Not quite sure why this would make any difference - PHP is case-insensitive for function/method names.

Comment: Yeh sorry I dont think this was the issue, seems I was a bit premature accepting an answer. Seems like this did not solve my issue. Although one email did send but they seemed to have stopped again.

Comment: Using this seems to have solved it $this->_mail->msgHTML($body, DOMAIN);