# PHPMailer html body rendering

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

I have this script that creates a table based upon data received from a csv file.
I would like to send this data to an emailaddress so I tried a PHPMailer.

Some luck so far. I got the basterd mailing but some of my export to the html body is created upon sending.

Can't figure out how to tackle that.

This is the basic PHPMailer

```
require("PHPmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.server.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->Username =  "email@server.com"; 
$mail->Password = "password"; 
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->From = "email@domain.nl";
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->AddAddress("email@somedomain.nl");
$mail->IsHTML(true);  

$mail->Subject = "Subjectrule";
$mail->Body    = "HERE I NEED TO PUT MY CODE</b>";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
```

This is the code that is being generated and the output from this should go in the body of the email but for the life of me I have no idea how to....
The idea is that if a person fills out an emailaddress all his/hers data is being generated and placed in the email body

```
foreach ($saved as $final){
    $bedrijf = $final['bedrijf'];
    $factuurnummer= $final['factuurnummer'];
    $gefactureerd = $final['gefactureerd'];
    $email = $final['email'];
        if ($bedrijf == $last_company) {
            echo '
            <font face="verdana" color="#868686" style="font-size: 12px;">
                <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20" rowspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="30">
                        <td width="340" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;">'.$factuurnummer.'</font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="140" align="right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;">'.number_format($gefactureerd, 0, ',', '.').'</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </font>';
        } else {
            $b = 100;
            echo '
            <font face="verdana" color="#808183" style="font-size: 12px;">
                <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr height="124">
                        <td width="180" valign="top">
                            <img src="../images/email/logo.jpg" width="180" height="124">
                        </td>
                        <td width="340" valign="top">
                            <table width="340" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr height="56">
                                    <td width="340" colspan="2" valign="top">
                                        <img src="../images/email/border-top.jpg" width="340" height="56">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="38">
                                    <td width="284" align="right"><font style="font-size: 20px;">&euro; '.number_format($arr_sum[$bedrijf] / $b, 2, ',', '.').'</font></td>
                                    <td width="56" valign="top">
                                        <img src="../images/email/border-right.jpg" width="56" height="38">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="30">
                                    <td width="340" colspan="2" valign="top">
                                        <img src="../images/email/border-right-large.jpg" width="340" height="30">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="228">
                        <td width="520" colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <img src="../images/email/squirrel.jpg" width="520" height="228">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="50">
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr height="40">
                        <td width="20" rowspan="3"></td>
                        <td width="480" colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb"><font style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>'.$bedrijf.'</strong></font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="30">
                        <td width="340" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>factuurnummer</strong></font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="140" colspan="2" align="right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;"><strong>Bedrag in EUR</strong></font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="30">
                        <td width="340" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;">'.$factuurnummer.'</font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="140" align="right" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb">
                            <font style="font-size: 12px;">'.number_format($gefactureerd, 0, ',', '.').'</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </font>';
            $last_company = $bedrijf;
            $sum=0;
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'U heeft geen emailadres ingevult wat bij ons bekent is.';
}
```

It does send and I do receive. The problem is that at the end of the code there are `variables` that are being updated. The problem is that if I place it within the html body the variables aren't being updated and I miss some values...

Comment: `$mail->Username =  email@server.com";`  Missing something? (Hint: `"`)

Comment: Well that's because I changed it for not wnating to have my own email online. It has the `"`. BTW I said that it does email

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why don't you just assign that html to a variable instead of echoing it out?

Comment: euhm.... well.... that does sound somewhat logical. I'm going to try that. Thnx

Comment: @jeroen is correct. You should be assigning the HTML to a variable and then calling `->isHTML(true);`. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code). It's gotta be called after otherwise the body doesn't get read as HTML.

Comment: You should have make email sending function and call it where you want in html body using variables.

Comment: @jeroen. Dude... Thank you for this insight... It worked perfectly

Comment: @Interactive Good to hear!