# PHP variable in html href

Tags: php, html

I am using a html email template for my account verification via email

so in my "register_session.php" i have integrated the PHPMailer and all in order to send an email to user. I have the following code:

```
 $email = $_REQUEST['email']; //to
 $subject = 'Account Verification';
 $message = file_get_contents('../emailhtml.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
 $header = 'From:Test' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n'; //set FROM HEADER
 mail ($email, $subject, $message, $header);
```

In my `$message` I used `file_get_contents` to retrieve the html code in `emailhtml.php`. Inside of `emailhtml.php`, I have my html & css code. See below:

```
<?php
include("../web/Includes/database_master_mysql.php");
$database_master = new DatabaseMaster();
$email = $_GET['email'];
$code = $_GET['code'];
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" class="emailButton" style="background-color: #3498DB;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" class="buttonContent" style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;">
            <a style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:135%;" href=" <?php echo'http://localhost/web/web/emailactivate.php?email='.$email.'&code='.$code.'';?> ">Confirmation</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I didn't put all the code because what my concern is in my href tag I wanted to redirect user upon clicking the button in their email to `http://localhost/web/web/emailactivate.php?email='.$email.'&code='.$code.'`

but what shows up in mine is:
`http://localhost/web/web/emailactivate.php?email%20=%3C?php%27.$email.%27?%3E&code=%3C?php%27.$code.%27%20?%3E`

I'm not really knowledgeable in PHP so it would mean a world to me if you'll help me. Thank you.

Comment: maybe change $message = file_get_contents('../emailhtml.php to $message = file_get_contents('../emailhtml.php?email='.$_GET['email'].' etc....

Comment: What you're looking at is called URL encoding. And you'll find a solution to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code

Comment: Use URL Encode on building your string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: The code you're importing with `file_get_contents` won't get executed by PHP. You'll need to import it and replace the variables manually.

Answer (score 0):

First, move the php code from your emailhtml.php to register_session.php and only leave html code in there.

Then for your mail() function put it in a variable to so you know if the mail was sent or not.

```
include("../web/Includes/database_master_mysql.php");
$database_master = new DatabaseMaster();
$email = $_GET['email'];
$code = $_GET['code'];
//$email = $_REQUEST['email']; //don't need this line. it's already set from the url request above.
$subject = 'Account Verification';
$message = file_get_contents('../emailhtml.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$header = 'From:Test' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n'; //set FROM HEADER
$send=mail ($email, $subject, $message, $header);

if($send){
   //email was successfully sent, do something
} else {
   //email did not send, check logs for errors
}
```