# Why HTML email is just showing code in php

Tags: php, email

Why HTML email is just showing code in php email. I am trying to send the email through php using elasticemail but showing the just code. I found somewhere that I should add the header like this. but the problem is i am not able to understand how can I add this code.

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

PHP email is showing just like this.

```
 $message = "<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>";
 $subject = "A New Quotation Recieved";
           $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
            $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
            $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
            $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');


            $mail->setTo('contact@mytrendin.com');
            $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode('Hello', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            $mail->setText($message);
            $mail->send();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPmailer sending HTML CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code)

Comment: That header-code looks like it's for PHP's built in `mail()`-function. You're using something else (we have no idea which) so you need to find out how to add HTML content using that library/class.

Comment: First of all What is the code of the object `Email` is that from a 3rd party library? Also does email has a method to set the body in html frorm. Usually emails have an Html body and optionally a plaintext one perhaps the method `setText` sets the **plaintext** body of an email.

Comment: Even though you are creating a header variable, you aren't passing it while sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - here you can also find some help. Try "A simple example" part as it might be the most useful.

I happen to work for Elastic Email. Hope you will resolve your problems and have great fun using our product :).

https://github.com/ElasticEmail/ElasticEmail.WebApiClient-php - you could also try to use this.