# Phpmailer sending email as plain text to emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

O am for the first time facing an issue with phpmailer, does anyone has any idea why phpmailer is sending email as follow? it somehow not tonverting the email into html contecn i just cannot seem to figure out why this is happening

```
no=reply@domain.com
6:16 PM (0 minutes ago)
to me

--b1_948b9a2ff8436cf0db01abf3e30c0373
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii


Request information form was submitted, details are given below.




                        Name
                        Email
                        Mobile
                        State
                        Plans
                        Destination
                        Total Travellers
                        Travel Within
                        Comments


                        debojit
                        no@email.com
                        451-245-7845
                        Georgia
                        Bags packed, I'm ready to go!
                        France
                        9 people
                        6-9 months
                        werwer




Regards,

company name



--b1_948b9a2ff8436cf0db01abf3e30c0373
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii


<h4>Request information form was submitted, details are given below.</h4>
<br/>
        <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td><b>Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Email</b></td>
                        <td><b>Mobile</b></td>
                        <td><b>State</b></td>
                        <td><b>Plans</b></td>
                        <td><b>Destination</b></td>
                        <td><b>Total Travellers</b></td>
                        <td><b>Travel Within</b></td>
                        <td><b>Comments</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>debojit</td>
                        <td>no@email.com</td>
                        <td>451-245-7845</td>
                        <td>Georgia</td>
                        <td>Bags packed, I'm ready to go!</td>
                        <td>France</td>
                        <td>9 people</td>
                        <td>6-9 months</td>
                        <td>werwer</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>               
<br/><br/>
Regards,
<br/>
company name



--b1_948b9a2ff8436cf0db01abf3e30c0373--
```

this is how i send mails

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->setFrom(senderemail);
$mail->addAddress(email);
$mail->addReplyTo($email);
$mail->subject($subject);
$mail->body($body);
//$mail->send();      
if($mail->send()){
     echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</div>';
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=contact-us.php'>";

    }else{
     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Some problem occurred, please <a href="contact-us.php">try again</a>.</div>';
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=contact-us.php'>";
  }
}
```

I tried adding $mail->IsHTML(true); etc but nothing seems to be working, what could be possible wrong here guys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPmailer sending HTML CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140263/phpmailer-sending-html-code)

Comment: @Justinas i tried steps from that post as well but it did not solve my problem, that is why i created this post. I have never faced this issue ever.

Comment: Got it sorted by adding the smtp login details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by enabling smtp login details

Answer (score 0):

This is complete fabrication that bears only minor resemblance to valid PHPMailer code – it's not even valid PHP! Unless you're using a wrapper/subclass that you have not told us about?

```php
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->setFrom(senderemail);
$mail->addAddress(email);
$mail->addReplyTo($email);
$mail->subject($subject);
$mail->body($body);
```

The PHPMailer class is called `PHPMailer`, not `Mail`. The subject is set using the `Subject` property; there is no such method as `subject()`. Similarly, there is no such method as `body()`; to set the body set the `Body` property. Overall it should be:

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setFrom($senderemail);
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->addReplyTo($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
```

PHPMailer does not do any HTML conversion. It's entirely up to you to create the HTML that you will send as part of the message body, and you also have to tell it you're using HTML, like:

```php
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Body = '<h1>Lovely HTML</h1>';
$mail->AltBody 'boring plain text';
```

**All** the docs and examples show you this, so perhaps you should give them a read.

Comment: Got it sorted by adding the smtp login details

Comment: That makes no sense! If your credentials were wrong, nothing would be delivered at all!